# Java regex for wrapping everything but some given character

Tags: java, regex

I have a String such as

```
somet3x70rnumb3r5.3.1*@:ch4r5*
```

I need to wrap everything that isn't `*`, star character, with a Pattern Quote `\Q...\E` and replace the `*` with `.*`. It should give this:

```
\Qsomet3x70rnumb3r5.3.1\E.*\Q@:ch4r5\E.*
```

I can do this with string traversal, splitting on `*` (or any character I specify), and building a string step by step, but I'd like to do use regexes and Pattern class utilities if possible.

Another example with specified character `?` which would be replaced by `.`:

```
123?4?
```

should give

```
\Q123\E.\Q4\E.
```

I was thinking of using groups, but I need groups around every zone because each has to be either wrapped or replaced by another character.

My goal is to create a Pattern `String` from a given `String` but only consider the areas matching the specified character and ignoring the rest (even if it contains regex patterns).

Comment: soyou basically wanna escape the matched string with a backslash ?? like ... `\somet3x70rnumb3r5.3.1.*\@:ch4r5\.*` and `\123.\4.` ??
`

Comment: No. I want the string areas around some specified character to be wrapped like `\Q<string area>\E` and the specified character to be replaced by some other. `\Q---\E` is used by Pattern to ignore anything inside it.

Comment: but AFAIK `\Qanythinghere\E` <==> `\anythinghere` in regex world .. check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html

Comment: I dunno about that, I think it needs the end tag, but I want only the `anythinghere` to be ignored by Pattern, while everything outside to be considered.

Comment: The example I gave above contains period `.`. This character would be considered as any character in a Pattern matcher, unless it was within `\Q\E`, then it would be considered as a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
String s = "abc*efg?123";
s = s.replaceAll("([^\\*\\?]+)", "\\\\Q$1\\\\E");
s = s.replaceAll("\\*", ".*");
s = s.replaceAll("\\?", ".");
```

Results in `\Qabc\E.*\Qefg\E.\Q123\E`

Comment: This means match everything but star and question mark in a group any number of times and replace them with wrapped versions?

Comment: Yes, anything that isn't a star or question mark will be wrapped in \Q and \E.  Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape the `?` or `*` inside the brackets. `"([^*?]+)"` works fine. Tested on a Java engine here: http://fiddle.re/g6gu

Answer (score 1):

It'll be simpler if you don't worry about building a one-liner. A one-liner is probably possible, but it will be a pain. Instead, I suggest you do something like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<!^)\\*(?!$)", "\\E.*\\Q")
         .replaceAll("(?<!^)\\?(?!$)", "\\E.\\Q");
str = "\\Q" + str + "\\E";
```

Simpler to write, and much easier to understand.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Sure, that's a *zero-width lookbehind assertion.* Check out [this regular-expressions.info page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/399649) for a much better explanation than I'll be able to come up with.